# Ubuntu: Copy terminal mouse selection automatically to clipboard for other apps?

Tags: ubuntu, copy-paste, gnome-terminal

I can use keyboard shortcuts and selecting text with the left mouse button allows me to insert the selection within gnome-terminal with the middle mouse button.

However, mouse selection with left button does not copy it to the clipboard and thus is not available to other apps.

I don't want to use the keyboard shortcuts when I select text with the left mouse button, I want to automatically have it in the clipboard (much like putty works on Windows).

Answer (score 2):

X and GTK+ maintain their own clipboards, which is why selecting text the X way does not automatically dump the selected text into the GTK+ clipboard. [gClip](http://gclip.uhvo.org/) can be used to bridge the two.

Comment: I installed it and ran it, but it does not copy the selected text. I looked at the settings, but can't find anything related. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looking at the web page, it says "Select (paint) something somewhere and click gClip tray-icon with mouse **middle** button." (Under **Use Primary Buffer**). Perhaps trying that would work.

Comment: I see. I'm searching for a solution which does that automatically.

Comment: Voting up, informative answer, yet not the solution yet.

Comment: The link is out of date. Searching for "gClip" returns either a patented "Granite clip" for stone masonry, or a "wave-shaping signal clipper".

Comment: Looks like the project is dead and gone. I'll leave it up for posterity, but if anyone knows of a current solution then I'll remove this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use General Purpose Mouse or gpm

```
sudo apt install gpm
```

The middle buttom (or scroll wheel) pastes.